# What kinds of fruits and vegetables could I plant here?

Tags: vegetables, fruits, sunlight, light

I am thinking of growing a garden in the area between the two fences in the photo. What kinds of fruits and vegetables would do well? It is not full sun, but by 10am most of the area has sun. If you are facing the fence, you are facing southeast. I live in northeastern Mississippi in zone 7b/8a. [image]

Comment: If facing the fence is looking south east, then the fence faces north west - unless it gets a minimum of 6 hours sun a day, its not an ideal spot for growing fruit and vegetables (except maybe fruit trees)

Comment: @Bamboo, thanks. I think it might get about 6 hours, but unfortunately much less than it would given the fence.